# Ускорение нахождения НОК двух чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал код для нахождения НОК заданных чисел, но он не вписывается в рамки времени. Подскажите пожалуйста как его ускорить.

```
b,n=map(int,input().split())
m=max(b,n)
while True:
    if m%b==0 and m%n==0:
        print(m)
        break
    else:
        m+=1
```

Время на работу программы 5 сек.

Comment: Приложите пример входных данных

Comment: Находит НОК заданных чисел

Comment: Например Ввод: 14 21. Вывод 42.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нашел интересный пример в интернете.
Как сказано на вики:

[image: вики]

```
import math
n = 14
m = 21

print((n * m) // math.gcd(n , m)) # gcd - greatest common devisor
```

[`gcd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) появился только в Python версии 3.5

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109052/discussion-on-answer-by-entithat---python).

Comment: До python 3.5, в том числе и в 2.7, был [fractions.gcd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd). Есть он и сейчас, но считается устаревшим по отношению к [math.gcd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd)

Answer (score 3):

После долгой, неплодотворной дискуссии - 
вот вам решение с нуля.

```
def gcd(a, b):
  while b:
    a, b = b, a % b
  return a
def mcd(n,m):
    return (n/gcd(n,m))*m  
print(int(mcd(n,m)))
```

При

```
n=14
m=21
```

ответ:

```
42
```

При

```
n=147
m=214
```

ответ 
31458

При

```
n=14783678656
m=21456735976
```

ответ

```
39651186209477312512
```

Время работы - моментально. Проверяйте.

P.S. 
math.gcd() реализовано в стандартной библиотеке начиная с версии Python 3.5

Answer (score 2):

В `Python 3.9` добавлена функция для нахождения НОК:

```
import math

print(math.lcm(14, 21))
```

Также можно воспользоваться `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.lcm(14, 21))
```